# What were the plans for governance of the Jerusalem International Zone?

Tags: israel, jerusalem

Had the 1947 partition plan of Palestine been accepted, there would have been an international zone centered around Jerusalem and Bethlehem until a referendum to be held at a later date.

A UN body would be in charge of it but what was the specific plan for the governance of this region? What citizenship would the people hold? Would it be a democracy? How would it behave economically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all spelled out in the [original document](http://unispal.un.org/unispal.nsf/0/7F0AF2BD897689B785256C330061D253). On a cursory reading, apparently there was no plan for separate citizenship of the City of Jerusalem.

Comment: my cursory reading differs "11. Citizenship. All the residents shall become ipso facto citizens of the City of Jerusalem unless they opt for citizenship of the State of which they have been citizens or, if Arabs or Jews, have filed notice of intention to become citizens of the Arab or Jewish State respectively, according to part I, section B, paragraph 9, of this plan."

Comment: @pugsville I stand corrected. As I said, I was only doing a cursory reading.

Comment: This is a broken link.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Darn, I'd have expected the UN to maintain their own documents...

Comment: @FelixGoldberg maybe they eventually went with a Two-Server Solution but they couldn't agree which side would get the document.